# Jquery click issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an issue about jQuery click event.According by followed code; while clicking "contactlist li a" specified item appends to "emaillist" as duplicate.What can cause it?When i check code by firebug, $(document).on("click", ".contactlist li a", function () {}); block works twice.

```
$.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetMailList", "Home")", {}, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, v) {
        $(".contactlist").append("<li><a tabindex='-1' href='javascript:'>" + v.Firstname + " " + v.Lastname + " - " + v.Title + " / " + v.Department + "</a></li>");
    });
});

$(document).on("click", ".contactlist li a", function () {
    $(".emaillist").Append("<li data-value='" + $(this).attr("data-value") + "'><i class='icon-user'></i>&nbsp;" + $(this).text() + "&nbsp;<a href='javascript:'>Delete</a></li>");
});

$(document).on("click", ".emaillist li a", function () {
    var i = $(".emaillist li a").index(this);
    $(".emaillist li").eq(i).remove();
});
```

Comment: you have to check whether there is any element before appending.

Comment: or use $(".emaillist").empty().append() for clearing the previous html.

Comment: What should happen if i click the item twice? Should it append only if it is not already present?

Comment: Thanks for replies ,i tried a couple of solution also above solutions  but problem continue.